# Webpack: Taking a long time to build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have an issue with webpack build times in my react application. Everything builds fine but it takes a long time.

Even I change just the JavaScript files the CSS rebuilds?

Also the CSS compilation is taking a longer than I think it should be (correct me if I am wrong)?

I am running a Core i7 with 16gb of Ram and the build is taking about a minute which is becoming very annoying during development when it's a one line change and you have to wait near enough a minute before you can see your changes in the browser?

Is this the wrong approach?

```
const CleanObsoleteChunks = require('webpack-clean-obsolete-chunks');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');

const config = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        "ehcp-coordinator": [
            APP_DIR + '/index.js'
        ]
    },

    output: {
        path: `${BUILD_DIR}/js/`,
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name]-chunk.js',
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['es2015', 'es2017', 'react', 'stage-0'],
                        plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties', 'syntax-dynamic-import',
                          ["import", {"libraryName": "antd",  "style": false}]]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [{
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    }, {
                        loader: "less-loader"
                    }]
                })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': "'development'"
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            'sourceMap': 'source-map'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: '[name].js',
            minChunks(module, count) {
                var context = module.context;
                return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("../css/[name].css")
    ],

    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./'),
            path.resolve('./node_modules'),
        ],
        extensions: ['.js', '.json']
    }

};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: I'd recommend only using `UglifyJsPlugin` and `ExtractTextPlugin` in production - they're pretty heavy in terms of compile time. Also, I think you can totally remove that `resolve` section of your config - it doesn't seem to meaningfully differ from the defaults.

Comment: Most people tend to either have a separate development and production config file, or (my preference) check `process.env.NODE_ENV` in the config script to conditionally enable/disable certain parts.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention this is the dev webpack config not the prod build one. Aslo why does it build the CSS when say only the JS has changed?

Comment: @JoeClay What you recommend I use to compile the less to css in development instead of the ExtractTextPlugin?

Comment: You can continue to use `less-loader` and `css-loader`, just feed them into `style-loader` instead in development. This injects the CSS into the head of the page at run-time rather than having it in a separate file.

Comment: Also, if you're not already, use `webpack-dev-server` rather than just running Webpack in watch mode - using the dev server compiles the files in memory instead of saving them to disk, which further decreases the compile times in development. It means you have to manually run a build when you want to have the files output, but you'll need to do that to switch to your production config anyway.

Comment: @JoeClay Cab you put the UglifyJsPlugin and ExtractTextPlugin suggestions and the other stuff in an answer, that has shaved it from 120,000 to 5,000 ms, thank you :)

Comment: For development atleast, you should specify --mode=development to webpack, along with --watch. It speeds up incremental builds a lot. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518655/webpack-taking-a-long-time-to-build/56070644#56070644

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, here are the most obvious changes you could make to speed up your build:

- `UglifyJsPlugin` and `ExtractTextPlugin` are very heavy in terms of their impact on your compilation time, while not actually presenting many tangible benefits in development. Check `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your config script, and enable/disable them depending on whether you're doing a production build or not.

  - In place of `ExtractTextPlugin`, you can use `style-loader` in development to inject CSS into the head of the HTML page. This can cause a brief flash of unstyled content (FOUC) when the page loads, but is much quicker to build.
- If you're not already, use `webpack-dev-server` rather than just running Webpack in watch mode - using the dev server compiles the files in memory instead of saving them to disk, which further decreases the compile times in development.

  - This does mean you'll have to manually run a build when you want to have the files written to disk, but you'll need to do that to switch to your production config anyway.
- Not sure if this has any impact on performance, but the `resolve` section of your config doesn't meaningfully differ from the defaults, and you should be able to remove it without causing any issues.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the webpack-dev-server at somepoint, we run ours using nginx as a proxy so not sure but the others definitely improved the build time.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I updated `devtool` property to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Article on Medium: https://medium.com/@gagan_goku/hot-reloading-a-react-app-with-ssr-eb216b5464f1

Had to solve the same problem for my React app ([HELO](https://www.heloprotocol.in/)) with SSR. Things get complicated with SSR, but thankfully webpack gets a lot faster if you specify `--mode=development`, because it does it in memory.

webpack-dev-server did not work for me because I need the client.js bundle for the SSR client to work properly. Here's my setup:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        client: './src/client.js',      // client side companion for SSR
        // bundle: './src/bundle.js',      // Pure client side app
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        {'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']},
                    ],
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 1000,
        poll: 500,
        ignored: /node_modules/,
    }
};
```

**package.json:**

```
  "scripts": {
    // IMP: --mode=development
    "run-dev-ssr": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch --mode=development & babel src -d dist --watch & browser-refresh dist/server.js"
  }
```

**.browser-refresh-ignore:**

```
node_modules/
static/
.cache/
.*
*.marko.js
*.dust.js
*.coffee.js

.git/

# Add these files to ignore, since webpack is storing the compiled output to assets/ folder
src/
dist/
```

Build times without mode:

```
Hash: 81eff31301e7cb74bffd
Version: webpack 4.29.5
Time: 4017ms
Built at: 05/10/2019 9:44:10 AM

Hash: 64e10f26caf6fe15068e
Version: webpack 4.29.5
Time: 2548ms


Time: 5680ms
Time: 11343ms
```

Build times with mode:

```
Hash: 27eb1aabe54a8b995d67
Version: webpack 4.29.5
Time: 4410ms

Time: 262ms

Time: 234ms

Time: 162ms
```

Comment: In my case, setting `mode: "development"` reduced ~10 second build time to less than .5 second, or almost instant. My project uses Svelte, ts-loader, and use dev-server. My project just started off but was giving 10 seconds to build the project. I think I didn't set `mode: "development"` because I thought that was the default, but the default is `"production"`. And OP's setting also misses this option.