# webpack wait until bundle finished taking so much time to build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I got an issue every time I want to run my react app it takes more than 10 minutes bundle to finished, it stack on these command

```
[webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished:
```

I have tried some solved question on google but it does not solved my problem
it makes me frustrated, any idea? thank you

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
```

const commonconfig = require('./webpack.common.config.js');

```
let config = merge(commonconfig, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: __dirname,
            publicPath: '/summary/',
        },
        historyApiFallback: true,
        client: {
            overlay: false, // There are reference errors coming from de-forms-ui; disable the warning overlay for now
        },
    },
});

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Update all the modules to the latest.  then `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use another builder, since webpack it's not the fastest one.

Anyway your problem might be due to your loaders (Tipically babel), so you could check [this reference](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#babel-loader-is-slow) from webpack documentation. Another possible fix might be [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518655/webpack-taking-a-long-time-to-build) from StackOverflow which is a similar issue

Some references form other builders:

1. Check [this blog](https://css-tricks.com/comparing-the-new-generation-of-build-tools/#aa-feature-comparison) from CSS Trick